# How to run tests from the command line of my PC on iphone

Tags: ios, selenium, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to connect remotely to iPhone in order to run on it tests that were created using selenium IDE.
I have the IP of the iPhone in a form of URL (The iwebdriver is running on the iPhone), but missing something within the commands.

Following is the command for selenium standalone that I'm trying to run by the command line:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
-hubHost "http://192.168.0.130:3001/wd/hub/" -browser browserName=iphone
-htmlSuite "*webdriver" "http://135.109.198.173/"  "IDEAutomation\Login.html" "IDEAutomation\Reports\Report.html"
-userExtensions "amartgwt3.0\smartgwt-3.0\selenium\user-extensions.js"
```

The URL that should be used in order to reach the iPhone is: "http://192.168.0.130:3001/wd/hub/"

The tests should run on the server: "http://135.109.198.173/"

*From an eclipse project it is possible to connect to the iwebdriver and run tests on iphone device.

Is there a solution for that issue ?